# How to CRUD from wordpress database in wordpress theme?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wpdb

I am in project where I am required to read certain data from a table (which table is created by my plugin, related to this project, I mean custom table, not the default tables of wp).

I use `$wpdb` object for database CRUD, to develop plugin, would that work for theme equivalently?

Please any help, Thanks in Advanced

Comment: Same object I guess, but database CRUD in theme looks not very common use case.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I have got solution through a small research, I tried with the object `$wpdb` and it worked 100% fine as it works in plugins. and the processes are the same as plugins.

Thanks to all who tried to answer my question.